# WCF - How to do Load Balance with WCF 4.0 Router Service

Tags: wcf, load-balancing, router

Have you ever learned about WCF Router Service 4.0?

I know that this new feature has a lot of advantages, but i have some questions about it...

1. Where can I find the documentation?
2. How to implement a logic for Load Balance over WCF Router Service 4.0?
3. How does WCF Router Service deal with services that has callback contracts?

Comment: How about http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx is a good start, too. [Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517421.aspx) might be best.

Comment: You might also enjoy http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=wcf%20routing%20service

Comment: About WCF Router you can check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd699773.aspx), good information about WCF Router Service.
and [here](http://robbincremers.me/2012/01/05/wcf-routing-and-load-balancing-based-on-message-content-with-routingservice-and-an-xpath-message-filter/) you can find good example about WCF Router and Load Balancing. Best regards

Answer (score 1):

1. you can use [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/772854/WCF-Routing-Service-Part-I-Basic-Concept-Simple-Ro) example
   2.you can use [enter link description here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/778575/WCF-Routing-Service-Part-III-Failover-Load-Balanci) this example

3.like cisco router
you must change example 1:

- change all conection to wsdual
  -define Icall back contact
  -change router to contract="System.ServiceModel.Routing.IDuplexSessionRouter"
  -change client to:

InstanceContext ctx = new InstanceContext(_CallBack);
                _Client = new DuplexChannelFactory(ctx, _EndpointName);
_Client.Open();

```
            _Chanel = _Client.CreateChannel();
```